# How to properly refer to a host from within a role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am currently using in defaults/main.yml:

```
myRoleName_host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
```

but some people feel we shouldn't use `ansible_host`. I know we
can reference from host_vars but from within the role you have no
guarantee about the host name, so that doesn't seem like a good option.
Or should `myRoleName_host` just be
a mandatory variable that the play has to set in order to call
the role?

Edit:
The goal is to allow the host to be written in the config files/templates that need to be on the server, as well as url variables that the role produces. Other roles depend on these url output variables.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well within the role there are config file, SQL files, urls that all need the actual host in them. Also We use this variable as an output/API that the role produces so other roles can reference it

Comment: Wouldn't the fact `ansible_facts.nodename` be safer then?

Comment: Is there an actual variable `ansible_facts.nodename` or by nodename do you mean using the actual group or host name from the inventory?

Comment: `inventory_hostname`, `inventory_hostname_short`, `ansible_fqdn` are some possible candidates to get the name of a host from inventory/facts.